# Jump to Protected Mode not working after linking the kernel

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I have been developing a Bootloader and have run into a problem when linking c++ code to my assembly stage2 code before I linked the files the second stage would jump to protected mode then to long mode without any problems but now after I have linked it there seems to be a problem when jumping to protected mode Here is the code I use to jump to protected mode:

```
main:            
;first stage of bootloader is loaded at the address 0x07c0:0 
        ;second stage of bootloader is loaded at address 0x200:0x0 


        cli 
   xor ax, ax         ; All segments set to 0, flat memory model 
   mov ds, ax 
   mov es, ax 
   mov gs, ax 
   mov fs, ax 
   mov ss, ax 
   ; 
   ; Set stack top SS:0xffff 
   ; 
   mov sp, 0x0FFFF 
   ; 


        mov [CDDriveNumber], dl 

        SwitchToProtectedMode: 
        lgdt [GDT_32];load the gdt 

        call EnableA20 



        mov eax, cr0 
        or eax, 1 
        mov cr0, eax 


        ; Flush CS and set code selector 
        ;   

        jmp 0x8:Protected_Mode 

        [BITS 32];Declare 32 bits 

        Protected_Mode:
```

Here is the GDT:

```
GDT_START: 
;null descriptor 
dd 0 
dd 0 
;data descriptor 
dw 0xFFFF 
dw 0 
db 0 
db 10011010b 
db 11001111b 
db 0 
;code descriptor 
dw 0xFFFF 
dw 0 
db 0 
db 10010010b 
db 11001111b 
db 0 
GDT_END: 
align 4 
GDT_32: 
dw GDT_END - GDT_START - 1 
dd GDT_START
```

Here is the linker script I use to link my c and assembly code

```
KernAddr = 0x200;
ENTRY(_Start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = KernAddr;

    .text : AT(ADDR(.text) - KernAddr)
    {
        _code = .;
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

   .data : AT(ADDR(.data) - KernAddr)
   {
        _data = .;
        *(.data)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
   }

   .eh_frame : AT(ADDR(.eh_frame) - KernAddr)
   {
       _ehframe = .;
       *(.eh_frame)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
   }

   .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - KernAddr)
   {
       _bss = .;
       *(.bss)

       /*
        * You usually need to include generated COMMON symbols
        * under kernel BSS section or use gcc's -fno-common
        */

        *(COMMON)
       . = ALIGN(4096);
   }

   _end = .;

   /DISCARD/ :
   {
        *(.comment)
   }
}
```

Here is the batch program I made to build everything:

```
nasm Stage1.asm -o Stage1.bin
nasm -f elf64 Stage2.asm -o Stage2.o
x86_64-elf-g++ -ffreestanding -mcmodel=large -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -mno-sse3 -mno-3dnow -c -o kernel.o kernel.cpp
x86_64-elf-ld -T linkerscript.ld -o Anmu.bin Stage2.o kernel.o -nostdlib
copy Stage1.bin Root
copy Anmu.bin Root
mkisofs -b Stage1.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-info-table -o BootLoader.iso ./Root
```

The rest of the code is available here: https://github.com/AnonymousUser1337/Anmu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that Stage2 is loaded at *segment* `0x0200`, which is address `0x2000`, but your linker says it starts at *offset* `0x0200`.

Also, despite naming your output "Anmu.**bin**", your file is actually still an ELF executable, which means all of the headers and whatnot are still present in the file. Instead, you need to use [`objcopy`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) to strip all of the headers and debugging symbols, giving you a flat binary:

```
objcopy -S -O binary Anmu.bin Anmu-flat.bin
```

Now, "Anmu-flat.bin" is nothing but code and data, and the first byte of the file is the start of the first instruction.

Comment: Thanks it worked but how would it still be an elf executable if it outputs it into a flat binary does it not format it when it links it??

Comment: Nope - linking still produces an ELF executable (even with the ".bin" extension).